# Multiple references with \autoref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am currently using the `\autoref` command from the `hyperref` package to refer to my theorems etc. However, I want to be able to (easily) refer to two or more theorems/lemmas/..., e.g. by calling something like `\autoref{lemma1,lemma2,lemma5}` -- where of course lemmas 1, 2 and 5 are labeled `lemma1`, `lemma2` and `lemma5` respectively -- so that the reference shows: "Lemmas 1, 2 and 5".

Can anyone help me with this? It doesn't seem to me like the `hyperref` package provides this functionality.

Minimal example

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}
\begin{document}
This is the first equation
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
and this is the second equation
\begin{equation}
\label{test}
\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = \gamma^2
\end{equation}
Referring to second equation here: \eqref{test}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you checked out the `cleveref` package?  It allows multiple references, with sorting and collapsing (e.g. turns "1,3,2,7" into "1--3 and 7"), among other nice things.

Comment: Yes, I have. But it doesn't seem to work well in my document. See an example here: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:197c
If I remove the `cleveref` package, the reference works.

It seems to conflict with `mathtools`' `showonlyrefs` option.

Comment: Yes, `mathtools` redefines the `eqref` command to do some extra things (writing to the `aux` file, specifically).  `Cleveref` also wants to patch the reference system, and the two don't play well together.  I think that it would be non-trivial to graft them together, because you'd need to pull apart a comma-separated list of label names then write them all to the `aux` file to make `mathtools` happy.

Answer (score 30):

**EDIT** added a way to set the plural names, which in effect gives foreign language support

I decided that I needed this feature of `\autoref` today and then I was surprised that I was unable to find it...so here is one way to define an `\Autoref` command that will do it. Specifically,

```
\Autoref{ref1,ref2,...}
```

will expand into the plural of the first reference followed by hyperlinks for all of the references. Here's the sample output from the MWE below:

[image: Sample for multiple <code>\autoref</code>'s]

There are a few minor(?) limitations in that the macro assumes that:

- all of the references are of the same "type" (so all lemmas, or all theorems etc)
- doesn't handle the optional argument to `\autoref` or the `*`-form (would be easy to fix...)
- it probably does not play well with equation references
- by default the plural form is obtained simply by adding an `s` to the "singular" name (so it is English centric). This can be overridden by defining a plural version of the autorefname, for example `\providecommand*{\lemmaautorefnameplural}{Lots of lemmas}`. A more realistic application would be to define plurals for other languages. The `...autorefnameplural` form is optional

The `\Autoref` macro behaves like `\autoref` when it is given one reference.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\makeatletter

% define a macro \Autoref to allow multiple references to be passed to \autoref
\newcommand\Autoref[1]{\@first@ref#1,@}
\def\@throw@dot#1.#2@{#1}% discard everything after the dot
\def\@set@refname#1{%    % set \@refname to autoefname+s using \getrefbykeydefault
    \edef\@tmp{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}%
    \xdef\@tmp{\expandafter\@throw@dot\@tmp.@}%
    \ltx@IfUndefined{\@tmp autorefnameplural}%
         {\def\@refname{\@nameuse{\@tmp autorefname}s}}%
         {\def\@refname{\@nameuse{\@tmp autorefnameplural}}}%
}
\def\@first@ref#1,#2{%
  \ifx#2@\autoref{#1}\let\@nextref\@gobble% only one ref, revert to normal \autoref
  \else%
    \@set@refname{#1}%  set \@refname to autoref name
    \@refname~\ref{#1}% add autoefname and first reference
    \let\@nextref\@next@ref% push processing to \@next@ref
  \fi%
  \@nextref#2%
}
\def\@next@ref#1,#2{%
   \ifx#2@ and~\ref{#1}\let\@nextref\@gobble% at end: print and+\ref and stop
   \else, \ref{#1}% print  ,+\ref and continue
   \fi%
   \@nextref#2%
}

\makeatother
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\providecommand*{\lemmaautorefname}{Lemma}
%\providecommand*{\lemmaautorefnameplural}{Lots of lemmas}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}1+1=2\label{one}\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}2+2=4\label{two}\end{lemma}
\begin{lemma}3+3=6\label{three}\end{lemma}

By \autoref{one}, \autoref{two} and \autoref{three} we are amazed.

By \Autoref{one} we are not amazed.

By \Autoref{one,two} we are a little amazed.

By \Autoref{one,two,three} we are quite amazed.

\end{document}
```

If you uncomment the line

```
\providecommand*{\lemmaautorefnameplural}{Lots of lemmas}
```

then the output is:

[image]

A more realistic use of this feature would be to add foreign language support.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! Sorry to bump this so late, but is there any way of changing the plural names? Adding an `s` at the end doesn't work for other languages..

Comment: @Guido I have added "foreign language support". It is now possible to define plural versions of the name such as `\lemmaautorefnameplural`. If these do not exist the plural form is still given by adding an s